# Flowable Subscriber: What request() method does actually?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Can anyone tell what the `request()` method in a `DisposableSubscriber` does and when it is used? We use it only when you create your own `Flowable` with `Flowable.create`? The official documentation says

> > **request(long n)**:
> >     Requests the specified amount from the upstream if its Subscription is set via onSubscribe already.

But I'm not understanding what does it mean. To try out I made a sample as below

```
private Flowable<Long> streamOfNums() {
    return Flowable.create(e -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            e.onNext((long) i);
            Log.d(TAG, "produced "+i);
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

Consumes it like

```
        streamOfNums()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<Long>() {

                @Override
                protected void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: ");
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "consuming data :"+aLong);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    request(4);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

And what I can see is each time the emitter produces numbers after the delay (2000 ms) given. I have given `request(4)` but even without that it works in the exact same way.
can anybody explain when what `request` does and when it is used. Can it be used for pagination scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` allows the consumer to tell the producer how many elements to produce. By default, `DisposableSubscriber` requests `Long.MAX_VALUE` in its `onStart()` method in which case further `request()` calls have no effect.

There is rarely the need to actually call `request` in such end-consumers, but otherwise you could use it to avoid buffer overflow when your end-consumer acts as an asynchronous boundary:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

Flowable.range(1, 500)
    .doOnNext(v -> Log.d("produced: " + v))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new DisposableSubscriber<Long>() {
            @Override protected void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStart: "); // <----- no super.onStart() here!
                request(1);
            }
            @Override public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: ");
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "consuming data :"+aLong);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    request(1);
                });
            }
            @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
                 executor.execute(() -> t.printStackTrace());
            }

            @Override public void onComplete() {
                 executor.execute(() -> Log.d("onComplete"));
            }
        });

Thread.sleep(100_000);
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: _**you could use it to avoid buffer overflow when your end-consumer acts as an asynchronous boundary**_ this is kind of not digesting. can you please explain this in simple words? May be with an example use case?

Comment: Also why you have used an `executor` in the sample?

Comment: I provided the example. Submitting tasks to an executor via its `execute` method is the async boundary. Also you don't have to worry about request if you consume the sequence synchronously, in which case calling `request(1)` from `onNext` directly only wastes computational resources. Synchronous consumption by nature act as a call-stack blocking thus `onNext` won't be called until the previous call to `onNext` returns.

Comment: Can we make use of this feature when you deal with pagination? Like request next `n` number of items only when user responds to the first `n` result set? Or this is not meant to deal with such a usecase?

Comment: Not really. You'd have to control the producer and the consumer tightly to avoid interference from in-between operators regarding the request amount. For example, an `observeOn` in between will not preserve whatever you requested. I suggest you search for `rxjava` and `paging` on SO.

Comment: Another question: Does Long.MAX_VALUE means infinite values or it's will be reduced to zero  eventually?

Comment: Long.MAX_VALUE means unbounded and is never decremented.